# WordPress /wp-content in a higher internet speed/higher latency datacenter

Tags: wordpress, dedicated-hosting, networking

Can I speed up WordPress site loading by moving the /wp-folder (containing themes, plugin files, images) to another server with higher latency but also a much faster connection?

Example: host website on low latency server (slow connection) and download files larger than 1mb from the other server (whose both connection speed and latency are 10x as much)

Comment: Have you considered using a CDN instead?   That is a lot simpler to set up.   How are you planning to point browsers to this other server?   Via a subdomain, a load balancer, or a a reverse proxy?   How are you planning to get the content to this other server when it is uploaded to WordPress?   What makes this other server higher latency, anyway?   Is it overloaded (cpu bound), but on a good network?

Answer (score 2):

You can't host /wp-content on a different server to the main site and use the same domain name to access it (unless you use a load balancer of some type which defeats the thrust of your question as the load balancer is a common bottleneck)

You talk about doing this in addition to a CDN - but this does not make sense. A CDN would redirect data to go through itself an would, with the appropriate caching solve the latency/bandwidth issues.

Of+course if you keep wp-content as it is and have an alternative domain with the large files on it, and cross link as appropriate that would seem to solve your problem.

Also, I have taken your claims about latency/bandwidth at face value as what you write is plausible , however it is a bit unlikely. To whit - minimum latency is largely defined by the distance of the links - if the bandwidth was low it would increase latency when congested.  Similarly files hosted on a high latency (even high bandwidth) link are likely to download more slowly then on a similar bandwidth link with lower latency because if the time waiting for acknowledgements.

Comment: @cvlo when I said wp-admin I did, of-course mean wp-content. As you believe I did not read your post I'll back off. I trust you looked at my profile on this and other stack exchange sites to establish to your satisfaction that I spout technical inaccuracies. I confess I don't know why you would then ask me to clarifying for you how cdn's work.

Comment: @cvlo please assume that people who answer your questions are doing so in good faith.   Your accusation that they did not read the question and that they have technical inaccuracies is unkind.  If somebody doesn't understand your question, there are better ways to respond.  What are the technical inaccuracies?

Comment: @davidgo I agree that your first sentence about the question showing lack of understanding is condescending.   I am going to edit it out of your answer.    It is better to just answer the question without pointing out that somebody doesn't understand.